# Pine Script outputting weird for loop error

Tags: for-loop, pine-script

Everything works except for loop. It's been outputting weird error:

> Script could not be translated from: for i = 1 to 10

```
study("RSI Below 25.3", overlay=true)


rsiValue = rsi(close, 14)
rsiValLow= rsi(low, 14)
x =low[1]


//for i = 1 to 10
//    if x > low[i]
//        x := low[i]   
            

isDivergent = abs(x-low[0])/low[0]*100 < .05 and abs(x- rsiValLow[0])>=1.5

isRsiOS = rsiValue <= 25

//plot signals to chart
plotshape(isRsiOS, title="Oversold", location=location.belowbar, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, text="Buy")
plotshape(isDivergent, title="Divergence", location=location.belowbar, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, text= "Divergence" )
```

I have been working on this for a while but cannot figure out why it won't work. Can you help?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you still need help on this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the minimum value, then it is better to replace the loop with a function `lowest`.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (RSI Below 25.3)", overlay=true)


rsiValue = rsi(close, 14)
rsiValLow= rsi(low, 14)

//x = low[1]

// for i = 1 to 10
//     if x > low[i]
//         x := low[i]   

x = lowest(low[1], 10)  // to replace the cycle          

isDivergent = abs(x-low[0])/low[0]*100 < .05 and abs(x- rsiValLow[0])>=1.5

isRsiOS = rsiValue <= 25

//plot signals to chart
plotshape(isRsiOS, title="Oversold", location=location.belowbar, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, text="Buy")
plotshape(isDivergent, title="Divergence", location=location.belowbar, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, text= "Divergence" )
//plot(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing:

//@version=4

That's all and nothing else was the problem and there for it concludes this question